# runsslserver command not working in django with executable built with pyinstaller

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I am using [runsslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver) command to run django application. on command line before generating its executable and its working fine For example,

```
Validating models...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 11, 2018 - 16:57:54
Django version 2.0.4, using settings 'XApp.settings'
Starting development server at https://0:8002/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (...
"sslserver",
...
)
```

when i built executable using [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) (i already included package in `.spec` file e.g, `Analysis(hiddenimports=[...,'sslserver',...])` and used with command `XApp.exe runsslserver 8000` then it shows message like,

```
Unknown command: 'runsslserver'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

How do i resolve it?

Comment: An installation or deployment and the development server don't fit together. Please read the page you have linked. There's a prominent warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution by adding **'runsslserver':'sslserver'** in **commands** dictionary in

`PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_django.py` file.

```
import django.core.management
import django.utils.autoreload


def _get_commands():
    # Django groupss commands by app.
    # This returns static dict() as it is for django 1.8 and the default project.
    commands = {
         'changepassword': 'django.contrib.auth',
         'check': 'django.core',
         'clearsessions': 'django.contrib.sessions',
         'collectstatic': 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
         'compilemessages': 'django.core',
         'createcachetable': 'django.core',
         'createsuperuser': 'django.contrib.auth',
         'dbshell': 'django.core',
         'diffsettings': 'django.core',
         'dumpdata': 'django.core',
         'findstatic': 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
         'flush': 'django.core',
         'inspectdb': 'django.core',
         'loaddata': 'django.core',
         'makemessages': 'django.core',
         'makemigrations': 'django.core',
         'migrate': 'django.core',
         'runfcgi': 'django.core',
         'runserver': 'django.core',
         'runsslserver':'sslserver',
         'shell': 'django.core',
         'showmigrations': 'django.core',
         'sql': 'django.core',
         'sqlall': 'django.core',
         'sqlclear': 'django.core',
         'sqlcustom': 'django.core',
         'sqldropindexes': 'django.core',
         'sqlflush': 'django.core',
         'sqlindexes': 'django.core',
         'sqlmigrate': 'django.core',
         'sqlsequencereset': 'django.core',
         'squashmigrations': 'django.core',
         'startapp': 'django.core',
         'startproject': 'django.core',
         'syncdb': 'django.core',
         'test': 'django.core',
         'testserver': 'django.core',
         'validate': 'django.core'
    }
    return commands
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had the same issue but for `runserver_plus` rather than sslserver. Used this method to fix by adding `'runserver_plus': 'django_extensions'`. Worked! Thx